# Not showing inside console window and network tab

Tags: html, angularjs, post, console.log

The second part is the html code and the first part is the angularjs part .

```js
customer.controller("new_info", 
  function($scope, $routeParams,$http)
  {    
    $scope.customer = {};
    $scope.register = function () {
      $http.post('localhost:4000/new_info', $scope.customer).then(
        function (response) { 
          console.log("posted successfully"); //not showing anything in the console window
        }
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form name="AddCustomer"  >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Id</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customer.id" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customer.name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customer.city" />
                </div>
                <button  class="btn btn-default" ng-click="register()">Submit</button> 
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

//after clicking the button its not showing anything .

Comment: Can you verify that your `register()` function in the controller is actually being called? If you can verify that, chain a `.error(function(err){ console.log(err); })` off your `.then()` and make sure you're not getting an error on your `$http.post()`. Can you use your browser's debugger and see the network traffic?

Comment: yes it is called . when I added the .error function, it tells me that there are no .then in $http so I switched to .success and now when I press the submit button , there is nothing written for the error console

Comment: it shows an empty space for the error console . It should show posted successfully

Comment: I'm confused. Let's start over...if you put things back the way they were when you started are you seeing the "posted successfully" text in the console?

Comment: nope I cannot see because that part is not happening for some reason . And no error is also given .

Comment: Now add a `.error()` chain since you know `.then()` is not being called. So it should be `$http.post(...).then(function(response) { console.log("posted successfully"); }).error(function(err) { console.log(err); });`.

Comment: It is telling that .then is not defined with $http . So i did .success and it was fine but there no answer as posted successfully . So for some reason .success is not called .

Comment: My bad...it's `.catch()`, not `.error()`.

Comment: it is showing Object { data: "", status: 0, headers: tc(), config: {…}, statusText: "" }

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, are you seeing the post network traffic? If you can see the traffic then you'll have to debug your back end and figure out why the post is unsuccessful. Is the URL on your `$http.post()` properly formed? Do you need to add `http://` on there?

Comment: 1) add http or https, if its the same domain just leave it as /new_info, 2) make sure you're looking at all requests in network tab and not filtering anything. This should work I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: No , nothing is shown.

Comment: check for console log errors.

Comment: Object { data: "", status: 404, headers: tc(), config: {…}, statusText: "" }

Comment: @lex don't need to add http or https . and I tried with just /new_info but still nothing is shown .

Comment: with http it worked .Thnks Lex